# Optimising lightbox2 for mobile as well as desktop in css

Tags: lightbox2

I am implementing a website for my dissertation at university and it includes a gallery. I downloaded the lightbox2 js file and got it working correctly.

My website is going to be optimised for mobile screens as well and was wondering how i would do this with lightbox2.

Comment: Please read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace line 306 (for v2.10.0) in a file lightbox.js:

```
maxImageWidth  = windowWidth - self.containerPadding.left - self.containerPadding.right - self.imageBorderWidth.left - self.imageBorderWidth.right - 20;

maxImageHeight = windowHeight - self.containerPadding.top - self.containerPadding.bottom - self.imageBorderWidth.top - self.imageBorderWidth.bottom - 120;
```

with following:

```
if (($(window).width() > 300) && ($(window).width() < 993)) {

maxImageWidth  = windowWidth - self.containerPadding.left - self.containerPadding.right - self.imageBorderWidth.left - self.imageBorderWidth.right - your values; 

maxImageHeight = windowHeight - self.containerPadding.top - self.containerPadding.bottom - self.imageBorderWidth.top - self.imageBorderWidth.bottom - your values;

} else {

maxImageWidth  = windowWidth - self.containerPadding.left - self.containerPadding.right - self.imageBorderWidth.left - self.imageBorderWidth.right - 20;

maxImageHeight = windowHeight - self.containerPadding.top - self.containerPadding.bottom - self.imageBorderWidth.top - self.imageBorderWidth.bottom - 120;

}
```

Or You can separately set width and height:

```
if (($(window).width() > 300) && ($(window).width() < 500)) {

maxImageWidth  = windowWidth - self.containerPadding.left - self.containerPadding.right - self.imageBorderWidth.left - self.imageBorderWidth.right - your values;

maxImageHeight = windowHeight - self.containerPadding.top - self.containerPadding.bottom - self.imageBorderWidth.top - self.imageBorderWidth.bottom - your values;

} 

else if (($(window).width() >= 500) && ($(window).width() < 993)) {

maxImageWidth  = windowWidth - self.containerPadding.left - self.containerPadding.right - self.imageBorderWidth.left - self.imageBorderWidth.right - your values;

maxImageHeight = windowHeight - self.containerPadding.top - self.containerPadding.bottom - self.imageBorderWidth.top - self.imageBorderWidth.bottom - your values;

} else {

maxImageWidth  = windowWidth - self.containerPadding.left - self.containerPadding.right - self.imageBorderWidth.left - self.imageBorderWidth.right - 20;

maxImageHeight = windowHeight - self.containerPadding.top - self.containerPadding.bottom - self.imageBorderWidth.top - self.imageBorderWidth.bottom - 120;

}
```

Do not forget to set your values.